# Manipulating Json (Before Passing to View)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

What I want to do is use functions like `->diffForHumans()`. As I am trying to get the data through ajax, I couldn't figure out how to manipulate json in javascript, so I decided to do it in server level.

My `$groups` data is like:

```
Group[1]['created_at']
Group[2]['created_at']
Group[3]['created_at']
```

and I am using `return $groups->toJson();` to return it to view.

I have 2 questions.

- How can I manipulate the json to be able to get it as `created_at` again but with diffForHumans() function? So I can call `Group[i]['created_at']` in javascript later, and get manipulated values for each.
- When I was returning to blade view, I was able to use functions like `{{{ (strlen($group->body) > 150) ? substr(($group->body),0,170)."..." : $group->body }}}`. Because I am using ajax, I think it's better also for this function to be carried on backend level, before getting passed in json.

Is this approach right? What's the best approach for what I am trying to achieve?

---

Edit on my first question:

I am able to get it as `dd($groups[2]['created_at']->diffForHumans());`
However, I couldn't make it work on:

```
foreach($groups as $key=>$group) {
   dd($group); // collection
   dd($key); // 0 
   dd($group[$key]); // null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to transform objects into arrays (and therefore losing the collection and the `toJson` method you could use the `transform` method.

```
$groups->transform(function($item, $key) {
    $item->created_at = $item->created_at->diffForHumans();
    return $item;
});

return $groups->toJson();
```

Answer (score -1):

> I couldn't figure out how to manipulate json in javascript, so I decided to do it in server level

Your data is totally ready to be processed in your Javascript.

To manipulate JSON in javascript, first you need to *parse* the JSON string into a Javascript object. To achieve this, use `JSON.parse()` method in your JS and access the object's properties as you'd do with any other Javascript object.

e.g.

```
var groups = JSON.parse(JSONgroups); // JSONgroups is the JSON passed to your view.
```

Now the following is possible with `groups` variable in your Javascript:

```
groups[1]['created_at']
```

**Regarding the edit:** The `$groups` variable is a *collection*, so in order to loop through it, you'll need to convert it to an Array as such:

```
$groupsArray = $groups->toArray();

foreach($groupsArray as $key => $group) {
  var_dump($group); 
  var_dump($key); 
  var_dump($group[$key]); // not possible since $key is the key to $group hence would return null
  var_dump($groupsArray[$key]); // use this instead
}
```

Comment: But, then I won't be able to use php functions.

Comment: I was asking php, and if there was an alternative way of using php function, in javascript json, I would love to know.

Comment: Thanks for your edit on your comment. Inside foreach, I tried  `$groupsArray[$key]['created_at'] = $group->created_at->diffForHumans();` however it didn't work. What is the way of doing it?

Comment: I didn't get you, did you want to be able to use the `$groups` variable in your JS?

Comment: Can you add the definition of the `diffForHumans()` method. You wont be able to use it with an array, one workaround would be to pass the values to it. e.g. `diffForHumans($groups[1]['created_at'])`.

Comment: No man, I have a collection $variables. I want to manipulate it so the data in the `created_at` field will be diffForHumans() version of the original one. (Just to make clear, _created at: 2015-10-17 21:55:46_ and diffForHumans _version: 15 hours ago_). If I can manipulate, then I can return it to view with `return $groups->toJson()`

Comment: diffForHumans($groups[1]['created_at']) won't work. I need to use it like `->diffForHumans()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92624/discussion-between-ahmad-baktash-hayeri-and-senty).

Comment: I wasn't the one downvoting the question. And thanks for your effort helping me